# Issue with col tags in react. Error: col is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In process of learning React.js with this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DDX3US3kss&t=1728s) at 35:50 min
getting problem with `col` tags. No surprise its is working for youtuber.

```
import React from "react";
import millify from "millify";
import { Typography, Row, col, Statistic } from "antd";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const { Title } = Typography;

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">  Global Crypto Stats </Title>

      <Row>
        <col span={12}> <Statistic title="Total cryptocurrencies" value="5" /> </col>
        <col span={12}>  <Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value="5" /> </col>
        <col span={12}> <Statistic title="Total Market cap" value="5" /> </col>
        <col span={12}> <Statistic title="Total 24h volume" value="5" />  </col>
        <col span={12}>  <Statistic title="Total Markets" value="5" /> </col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Error in browser:
[image]

No beginners luck *sigh* :(

Answer (score 2):

You have the case of `col` wrong.

In lower case, `col` represents the [HTML `<col>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col), which can only be an empty element.  However, `Col` with an upper-case `C` appears to be a component from the `antd` library.  See for example its use [here](https://2x.ant.design/components/grid/#components-grid-demo-playground).  Also, if you pay close attention to the video, it indeed uses `<Col ...>` rather than `<col ...>`.

Change `col` to `Col` in your `import` statement and in the various `<col ...> ... </col>` lines.